# python regex not matching request log message

Tags: python, regex

so I tested out this [regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5B0-9a-z%5C-%5D*(.gif%7C.GIF))%20(HTTP%2F1.0%22)%20(200)&test_string=%2Fas2-df1.GIF%20HTTP%2F1.0%22%20200%200&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) but when I try it out in python shell I don't get any matches.

```
In [42]: r = re.match('([0-9a-z\-]*.gif) (HTTP/1.0") (200)', '/asdf.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 0')

In [44]: print(r)
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a forward slash at the beginning of the pattern; Keep in mind [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) always matches the pattern from the beginning of the string, so everything should match from the start:

```
r = re.match('/([0-9a-z\-]*.gif) (HTTP/1.0") (200)', '/asdf.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 0')
#             ^

r.group()
# '/asdf.gif HTTP/1.0" 200'
```

Comment: I need to get away from the computer and take a break... Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use `re.search()`, `re.match()` need match the start of the string, `re.search()` will scan through the string.